# CodeIgniter cookies preserved across multiple servers

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I have a load balancer and two servers. I am having trouble with CodeIgniter's cookies (CodeIgniter's sessions) not being preserved between the two servers. Half of the time the cookie is preserved, and the other half of the time, it is lost. It seems like the cookie isn't being preserved across the two servers.

Help!

Comment: Are the servers set to the same time?  If one server's much farther ahead than the other, cookies set by it may appear expired to the other.

Comment: the time on both servers is identical

Comment: Have you thought about DB based sessions?

Comment: DB sessions fixed it! Along with setting up the load balancer so that the user's actual ip is sent to the servers.